# C++ returning a non-const method in a const method

Tags: c++11, constants

I came across this weird issue

I have a method that is a const, per se:

`void doSomething() const { x(); }` and x is a non-const method.
Compiling would result in a `discards qualifiers` error.

say I turn `doSomething` to `int`, and make `x` return some dummy int, and it turns into:

`int doSomething() const { return x(); }`

Is it normal that it would compile? it does compile on my compiler, which leads me to think this might be a compiler bug.

The compiler version is: `gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5`

---

```
class GgWp
{
public:
    int doSomething const { return x(); }
    int x()
    {
        num = 5;
        return 0;
    }
private:
    int num;
}
```

As you can see, `x` modifies the variable `num`

Comment: No, that should give the same error, but it's very unlikely to be a compiler bug. Please provide a complete example showing the problem.

Comment: the edited code snippet above could not possible be your actual code, since `doSomething` lacks `()`

Comment: It doesn't matter if `x` actually modifies anything or not, a member function marked as `const` simply can't call a member function not marked as `const`.

Comment: Your example doesn't compile (missing `()` after `doSomething`). Please provide a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and make sure it actually compiles.

Comment: http://ideone.com/B5uwIR does not compile with the expected error. Why would it compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this line:

`int doSomething() const { return x(); }`

If `x()` is a *member function* then it must be `const` or this will not compile on any major standards-compliant compiler. This has nothing to do with whether or not you actually return the value of `x()` or whether you return anything from `doSomething()`. You can't run a non-const function from a const function.

If `x()` is not a member function then this doesn't apply.

Comment: Yup. So that's my answer. The code I provided indeed didn't compile

Answer (score 1):

The `const` *after* the function name refers to the object (`this`)
, so you should not be able to call `x()` (if `x` is not `const`) from a `const` method, and return types should make no difference.

If it compiles anyway, either `x()` is not a member, it's `const`, or
your compiler is malfunctioning.